# Catching errors from new T()

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.ios

I normally use this pattern for lazy loading from a base screen class:

```
public class BaseScreen
{
    public void Goto<T>(T t) where T : BaseScreen, new(){
        if (t == null)
            t = new T();

        NavigatonController.PushViewController(t,true);
    }
}
```

But I have run into a situation that I don't like. When an exception is thrown in the process of constructing t, that exception is ignored an instead you get an excepton at `t = new T()`. It says something like: `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`. But it doesn't give any hint of where the real exception happened. I have tried catching it but still found no info. Of course, eventually I found it but I would like to know if there is a way to catch these errors directly. I throw exceptions to help me know if I have done something wrong but it is pointless if the only exception I am going to see is the one I mentioned before. Therefore, can I do something? or is this just a poor pattern?

Comment: Check inner exception instead

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you (you should post it as an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check InnerException to get the real cause of error

Comment: IMHO this is the right answer, so it's fine as it is.